# Simple Open Auction example - how to run it?

Tags: solidity, remix, ganache

I'm trying to run [Simple Open Auction](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/solidity-by-example.html#simple-open-auction), compiled successfully in Remix. I receive "Exception while processing transaction: revert" when I try to enter recipient account addresses from Ganache, or "Attempting to run transaction which calls a contract function, but recipient address 0xf26a88E8DC89f97273BE2B9211852534E65C1299 is not a contract address", when I enter created contract address from Transactions Ganache tab. How to run this contract?

Comment: It worked for me on remix. What were your deployment parameters? They should look something like this: `"1","0x318B06Caac22f4D4a36Aab9bC502528CCDeFD393"`

Comment: I rechecked parameters and noticed that I set 10 ether value at contract running, so I set it to 0 and then successfully launched that contract, thank you! I thought it would be better to attach some ether to contract, but looks like it doesn't =)

Comment: You should feel free to post an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted. This may help others in the future who run into a similar issue!

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi, ok, I'm waiting for accepting answer in 11 hours for now, as told when I press on tick icon

Answer (score 0):

I rechecked parameters as @shane advised and noticed that I set 10 ether value at contract running, so I set it to 0 and then successfully launched that contract, thank you! I thought it would be better to attach some ether to contract, but looks like it doesn't =)